# How to record and use your own voice for text to speech synthesis?

Tags: speech

Is it possible these days to, say, record yourself pronouncing every consonant and vowel in your target language, and then using those sound snippets to dynamically generate the pronunciation of words and such? I am looking to produce 22 consonants with 5 vowels, so 110 combinations/pairs, at each of 12 notes, so over 1000 sound snippets, which is like an hour of pure recording.

Is there some way somehow to use [some tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#Open_source) to turn these primitive sound snippets into full on words / text-to-speech? Or is there a big gap between having these sounds and making them work in an existing open source library? If it's not possible to use a simple library and plugin your own voice, what are the high-level steps you would take to make it possible by hand or writing some custom software?

Sort of like [this](https://emvoiceapp.com/):

> Emvoice takes a different approach. We've broken record vocals down to the granular level, recording the elements that make up individual phonemes at multiple pitches. Thousands of samples are reconstructed by a sophisticated cloud-based engine that returns the complete vocal to your system over the internet. What you're hearing when you listen to Emvoice One isn't artificial - it's a real singer's voice interpreting your own words.

But plugging in your own voice.

Answer (score 2):

**AI VOICE CLONING!!!**

Depending on your voice, you might easily get great results by recording a couple minutes and uploading it to https://beta.elevenlabs.io/voice-lab

All you need to do is speak normally and casually, just ramble on or read some paragraphs (if you want the result to sound a touch more "formal").

I find in my case, I have idiosyncratic pronunciation so it doesn't "get me" as well as some of my friends. But I've heard some uncanny resemblances, down to filler words and phrasing — which is a huge part of it.

I've evaluated various AI text-to-speech services and this one really takes the cake with the amount of expressivity. If you wanna check out some others, https://www.futuretools.io/?tags-n5zn=text-to-speech